# compare two similar python code (Project Euler # 3)

Tags: python, execution

I have two codes for solving [Project Euler #3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3).

The first one is

```
x = 600851475143
a = 2
max = 0
while a < x:
    for i in range (2, int(a**0.5)+1):
        if a % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        if x % a == 0 : max = a
    a += 1
print(max)
```

second one is

```
x = 600851475143
a = 2
max = 0
while a < x:
    for i in range (2, int(a**0.5)+1):
        if a % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        if x % a == 0 : print(a)
    a += 1
```

Both are written in python

As you guys can see the only difference is whether I put final value in variable 'max' and print it later or just print out it in if statement. But there is a big difference on execution speeds of these two. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case there is  max = a  which is an assignation, which takes some extra time to be computed, it shouldn't be a lot of difference thou.